# Using ADOX via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, ms-access-2010, adox

Shouldn't you be able to implement the ADOX library via VBScript? The code below runs perfect via Access 2010 on Windows 7, Office 2010 32-bit, but doesn't via a VBScript. Isn't ADOX just another COM Object like say FileSystemObject?

```
Dim objADOX

Set objADOX = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
objADOX.ActiveConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Zamdrist\Desktop\Work\Scripts\Shell.accdb"
MsgBox objADOX.Tables.Count
```

Sorry, I should point out, VBScript complains that the provider does not exist. Odd because I do in fact have Access 2010 installed.

Comment: Yep, ADOX should work fine. If it didn't, you'd get an error on the `CreateObject()` line. Your error is happening on the `ActiveConnection` line. Are you on 64-bit Windows 7? If so, are you using the 64-bit version of `WSCRIPT.EXE`? You'll probably need to use the 32-bit version of `WSCRIPT` to access the 32-bit OLEDB drivers.

Comment: The 32-bit versions of `wscript.exe` and `cscript.exe` can be found in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Comment: Bond, if you want to answer this I'll mark is as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not meant as an answer just simply as a tip that has helped me tremendously. I am constantly working with providers that only work with 32 bit so i always add the attached code to all of my scripts. This way it doesn't matter if the machine that is executing the code is 32 or 64 bit.

```
'Check for 64 bit and run as 32 bit if needed.
'On error resume next

Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oWs = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

windowsdir = oWs.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")

If InStr(LCase(WScript.FullName), windowsdir & "\system32\") And oFso.FolderExists(windowsdir & "\SysWow64") Then       
    oWs.Run windowsdir & "\SysWow64\WScript.exe """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """"
    WScript.Quit
End If

'code to run as 32 bit
```